# Messaging Application only gets Security Certificates Once

Tags: security, certificate, messaging, xmpp

I'm developing a messaging application that runs within a larger program.  When the user logs off in the main program, an event is triggered to log them off in my module.  The same occurs for log on.  Right now the first user gets in fine, but there is an error about accepting the security certificate every time the second user tries to get in.  I have no idea why this error would exist as the first user gets in fine, and the logic is the same.  I know this isn't a ton to go on, but are there any obvious things I should check?

I'm using C# with Jabber.NET as my main XMPP library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wire up the OnInvalidCertificate callback in one and not the other?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the XMPP library may be buggy.  It seems like the user isn't completely getting signed out, which would break the reconnect.